# how to send a message to a view ajax-like

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know about a pattern to do this. I have a controller with method1()

```
method1(){
 return View();

}
[httpost]
method1(string something){

  return View(object);
}

[httpost]
method2(int? id){

  return redirectToaction("method1");
}

View:
<div>
beginform(){
   textfield
   submit button
}
</div>
<div>
if(viewbag.something != null){
   beginform("method2", "controller", new{id=number}){
     <span>@model.info</span>
     submit button
    }
}
</div>
```

and this displays a view this view has a form a text field and submit and this calls method1() but with the HTTPPOst and in the same view i display another form which will call method2() my question is how can i display a message in the view? like "user has been deleted" without having to create another view. Is there another way of doing this in asp mvc or do i have to include ajax?

I tried setting a viewBag inside method2, but since method2 redirectsaction to method1 it somehow does not stay, and it is not displayed in the view.
Thanks!

Comment: So I am guess through the vagueness of your question that method1() presents a drop down list of users and method2() is information about your users.  And you want "user has been deleted" to show up if they select a deleted user (that still shows up) on method1()?

Comment: OR is method2() used to delete the user and you want feedback that the user has been deleted?

Comment: method2 deletes the user and i want it to display a message in the same view, but wanted to know if i can do this on asp mvc or if i have to add ajax to asp mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use TempData which is preserved between a single redirect:

```
public ActionResult method1() 
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult method1(string something)
{
    return View(something);
}

[HttpPost]
publicActionResult method2(int? id)
{
    TempData["message"] = "User has been deleted";
    return RedirectToAction("method1");
}
```

and in the view display the message:

```
<div>@TempData["message"]</div>
```

If there is no message in `TempData` it will simply display an empty `div`. You could further check if `TempData["message"] != null` in the view if you didn't want the empty div.